# Make child scrollable while maintaining parents padding

Tags: html, css, parent-child, padding

I want to make a child div (*.content*) to be scrollable if its exceeding its parents height. The problem I encountered is maintaining its parents padding (*.box* padding), so that *.content*´s text isn't placed right at the bottom edge.

The *.box* height is not fixed at 250px, just for demonstration purposes.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08ea4ehm/)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
 <h3>Title</h3>
 <div class="content">
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px; //height is not fixed, just for demonstration purposes.
  padding: 25px;      
  overflow: hidden;

  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.content {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the title as always fixed?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that, title height isn't fixed either. The .content div should take up the available space.

Comment: So if I understand right, you want .content to be the height of .box minus its margins and minus whatever height is taken up by <h3>Title</h3>?

Comment: Minus its padding not margin, but yeah besides that exactly how I want .content to behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this CSS:

```
.box {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.content {
  flex:2;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;//only for y axis
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/08ea4ehm/4/

Comment: Exactly what I needed, you saved my day - I really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh a small warning, the flexbox standard may not work on some older browser and may require some vendor tags. Take a look here to see how to best maximize compatibility: https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the height for your content area box rather than assign a height for your parent box which can maintain the padding you want.

```
.box {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.content {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femiva/6h1h1atu/)

Comment: I think he wants the content area to fill up all the space available in .box no matter the height of box.

Comment: Thanks for your time, though the problem is that the height isn't fixed to 250px hence it wouldn't work out like that.

Comment: So you want to have a fixed height for the parent div? without having any fixed width for any one of them i think its not possible to make it scrollable. I think with flex tables its possible for you.

Comment: You are right @Ting Sun, he might be looking for the content area available space only